# Автоматизация проверок сайта на типовые уязвимости

Tags: безопасность, тестирование

В этом вопросе хочется собрать список устанавливаемых локально решений и онлайн-сервисов, позволяющих автоматически протестировать сайт на типовые уязвимости, такие как XSS, CSRF, SQL инъекции, открытые листинги каталогов, открытые файлы конфигов, открытые `.svn` и `.git`, открытые `phpinfo()` и проч.

Задача - провести тестирование сайта перед его выкаткой в продакшен с минимальной ручной работой, в идеале - скормить сервису URL сайта и нажать кнопку "Go!", на выходе получив список уязвимостей с сортировкой по типу/критичности.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.tinfoilsecurity.com - требуется регистрация и подтверждение владения сайтом (через DNS или выкладывание проверочного файла), после чего возможна автоматическая проверка на наличие известных системе уязвимостей. По найденным уязвимостям строится отчёт, по каждой уязвимости даются ссылки на материалы для изучения матчасти и способов закрытия уязвимости. Системе можно сказать "эту дырку я закрыл" и инициировать перепроверку - система ответит, действительно ли уязвимость перестала воспроизводиться. Работает небыстро, ругается на любые HTTP формы без капчи и на insecure куки, то есть в реальном большом проекте даст много ложно-положительных срабатываний. Первый месяц работает бесплатно, дальше - либо [за деньги](https://www.tinfoilsecurity.com/pricing), либо урезанный функционал.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно Яндекс [выпустил](http://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/256463/) своё [открытое](https://github.com/antimalware/manul/) решение для сканирования сайтов на уязвимости - [Manul](http://yandex.ru/promo/manul).

Надо скачать .zip архив, распокавать его у себя на сайте и просто зайти на www.example.com/manul браузером - вся работа происходит прямо там.

При сканировании Manul собирает информацию обо всех файлах, лежащих в корневом каталоге и ниже его, — об их размере, дате модификации, вычисляет хэш-суммы. Параллельно каждый файл проверяется на вредоносность по приложенной антивирусной базе и помечается одним из трех флажков:

- желтый — в файле присутствует подозрительный код, который по различным признакам может оказаться вредоносным;
- красный — в файле присутствует известный Манулу вредоносный код;
- зеленый — в файле не найдено ничего подозрительного.

Завершив проверку, Manul сохраняет всю полученную информацию в виде XML. Фрагменты кода — как подозрительные, так и вредоносные — также прикладываются в отчет. Для просмотра отчета предлагается специальный [онлайновый просмотрщик](http://yandex.ru/promo/manul/analyzer/).