# Разработка сайтов и контроль версий

Tags: git, веб-программирование, контроль-версий, развертывание

Не могу разобраться с git.
Есть два доменных имени (директорий на сервере)

```
dev.example.com (www/dev.example.com)
```

и

```
example.com (www/example.com)
```

Как развернуть разработку таким образом, чтобы *www/example.com* рабочим сайтом, а в *www/dev.example.com* вносились правки, после чего слияние веток, и *www/example.com* становится актуальным.

P.S. Как такое же провернуть для баз данных MySQL

Comment: Вас интересуют команды гита или как сделать, чтобы это происходило автоматически? Т. е. разработчик сделал git merge dev, изменения попали в master и автоматически отобразились на сервере?

Comment: Команд думаю будет достаточно, для автоматизации я смогу сделать шеллскрипт

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, резервное копирование баз данных средствами VCS нерационально. Есть инструменты лучше.  Но это возможно: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13608706/2790048, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4261480/2790048

Answer (score 1):

репозиторий выносите в какой нибудь `~/home/www/github/*`
ваши `www/dev.example.com` и `www/example.com` разворачиваете на основе вашего репозитория. все.

Бд можете иметь тоже одну и подключать к обеим сайтам или же добавить  `*_dev.db`

*(я не знаю что еще тут добавить. Если не доступно описал в комментариях распишу)*

Comment: то бишь просто клонирую `~/home/www/github/*` в `www/dev.example.com` и `www/example.com` а потом их сливаю после внесения правок на `www/dev.example.com`?
А если организовать реп в `www/dev.example.com`, и после всех изменений, сливать с `www/example.com`?

Comment: после этого у Вас единственный репозиторий с которым Вы работаете.   Как организовать внутреннюю его структуру об этом много написано и тут разные подходы. 
Как вариант у Вас может быть основная ветка пусть будет `master` и ветка `develop`. В `master` мержится `develop` после завершения и тестирования Ваших разработок. В `develop` мержатся ветки в которых идет разработка
на `www/example.com` у Вас - `master`
на `www/dev.example.com`  - `develop`

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему таким образом:

1. Развернул текущую версию сайта на **/var/www/dev.example.com**
2. Создал репозиторий `cd /var/www/dev.example.com` `git init`
3. Добавил все файлы `git add *` и создал коммит `git commit -m 'DEV repo init'`
4. Клонировал репозиторий из **/var/www/dev.example.com** в **/var/www/example.com** `git clone /var/www/dev.example.com /var/www/example.com`

Теперь порядок работы такой:

1. Внес изменения на **/var/www/dev.example.com**
2. Добавил все изменения `git add *` и создал коммит `git commit -m 'Updated!'`
3. Применил изменения в клонированном репозитории **/var/www/example.com** `cd /var/www/example.com` `git pull`
4. GOTO 1

Comment: Тут есть пара проблем: 1) Репозиторий на example.com занимает много места, больше чем сам сайт 2) В нем хранятся все версии, а не только текущая 3)Получив доступ к нему, можно добыть неинтерпретированные, исходные версии файлов, которые иначе не были бы видны.

Comment: Это не есть хорошо... Таки придется выносить репозиторий...

Comment: через rsync или git-sync вариант как вам?

Comment: Вариантик не плохой, спасибо. А доступ к `/var/www/example.com/.git` я прикрыл с помощью `.htaccess`

Comment: ну, когда совсем нечего воровать — все–таки надежнее, чем когда оно под замком лежит.

Comment: кстати, вот нашел в тему вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/422173/181472

Answer (score 0):

[Процесс можно автоматизировать с помощью git-hooks.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428514/181472)

1. Делаете коммиты на dev в рабочей ветке.
2. Когда фича завершена, делаете тесты и что там ещё нужно.
3. Merge в master.
4. Возможно, еще раз тесты.
5. Push на remote.
6. Там скрипт сам производит развертывание.

> **Важно: любой метод с хранением репозитория на одном сервере с сайтом уязвим!** Вместо этого вы можете использовать Git, чтобы он работал с рабочей областью на удаленном сервере.